# Break data frame in half with condition

Tags: r

I have a data frame

```
mydata = data.table(MyTimes = as.POSIXct(c("2015-01-01 00:00:03","2015-01-01 00:00:04","2015-01-01 00:00:18","2015-01-01 00:00:48","2015-01-01 00:00:48","2015-01-01 00:00:54","2015-01-01 00:01:12","2015-01-01 00:01:45"),tz = "GMT"),othercol= c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))


 mydata
               MyTimes othercol
1: 2015-01-01 00:00:03        1
2: 2015-01-01 00:00:04        2
3: 2015-01-01 00:00:18        3
4: 2015-01-01 00:00:48        4
5: 2015-01-01 00:00:48        5
6: 2015-01-01 00:00:54        6
7: 2015-01-01 00:01:12        7
8: 2015-01-01 00:01:45        1
```

the data is sorted by time and I would like to break this data frame into 2 data frames with 2 conditions:

1. the break should occur in the middle if possible
2. BUT times near the break with the same SECOND must be in the same dataframe

So in this example there are 8 rows and I'd like to break it in the middle. 4 rows each BUT notice 00:00:48 would be in two dataframes and that is not possible based on point #2 above. Meaning when you make the break you cannot break the same second.

So the data frames here could be

```
data frame 1:
                   MyTimes othercol
     2015-01-01 00:00:03        1
     2015-01-01 00:00:04        2
     2015-01-01 00:00:18        3
     2015-01-01 00:00:48        4
     2015-01-01 00:00:48        5

data frame 2:
     2015-01-01 00:00:54        6
     2015-01-01 00:01:12        7
     2015-01-01 00:01:45        1
```

or it can be like this:

```
data frame1:
   2015-01-01 00:00:03        1
   2015-01-01 00:00:04        2
   2015-01-01 00:00:18        3

data frame2:
    2015-01-01 00:00:48        4
    2015-01-01 00:00:48        5
    2015-01-01 00:00:54        6
    2015-01-01 00:01:12        7
    2015-01-01 00:01:45        1
```

either way the 00:00:48 is in the same data frame

Comment: your example data generates warnings

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
split(mydata, as.numeric(mydata$MyTimes) < median(as.numeric(mydata$MyTimes)))
$`FALSE`
               MyTimes secondcol
1: 2015-01-01 00:00:48         4
2: 2015-01-01 00:00:48         5
3: 2015-01-01 00:00:54         6
4: 2015-01-01 00:01:12         7
5: 2015-01-01 00:01:45         8

$`TRUE`
               MyTimes secondcol
1: 2015-01-01 00:00:03         1
2: 2015-01-01 00:00:04         2
3: 2015-01-01 00:00:18         3
```

Comment: nice. I was working on a `data.table` solution (`library(data.table)

setDT(mydata)[, grp := rleid(MyTimes)]
split(mydata, mydata$grp == ceiling(max(mydata$grp)/2))`) which is similar in logic to yours (but yours is simpler and more elegant :) )

Comment: @DatamineR  I get this error Error in .Call("Crbindlist", l, use.names, fill) : 
  "Crbindlist" not resolved from current namespace (data.table)

Comment: @user3022875 I will take a look at this tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as @DatamineR 's solution, but an alternative using run-length-encoding is

```
library(data.table)

mydata[, grp := rleid(MyTimes)]  ## put times into groups
split(mydata, mydata$grp >= ceiling(max(mydata$grp)/2))

$`FALSE`
               MyTimes othercol grp
1: 2015-01-01 00:00:03        1   1
2: 2015-01-01 00:00:04        2   2
3: 2015-01-01 00:00:18        3   3

$`TRUE`
               MyTimes othercol grp
1: 2015-01-01 00:00:48        4   4
2: 2015-01-01 00:00:48        5   4
3: 2015-01-01 00:00:54        6   5
4: 2015-01-01 00:01:12        7   6
5: 2015-01-01 00:01:45        8   7
```